# Maintain column widths of a DataGrid when a grouping option changes

Tags: c#, data-binding, wpf-controls

I've been using [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) for a while now to improve my VBA code. The ducky introduced me to unit tests and lots of other proper techniques. In gratitude I'm trying to give back and contribute a fix to an issue I found, in spite of not knowing C#.

The issue deals with a `System.Windows.Controls.Grid`. The grid has an option of grouping tests results by their outcome or by the module they reside in. If a column width is adjusted and then the grouping is changed the width change isn't reflected.

I've created properties on the viewmodel that I thought would allow two way binding, one shown below as an example.

```
private DataGridLength _outcomeColumnWidth;
public DataGridLength OutcomeColumnWidth
{
    get => _outcomeColumnWidth;
    set
    {
        _outcomeColumnWidth = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    } 
}
```

I've edited the XAML trying to create a `TwoWay` binding that will have the changed column width persist after the grouping is changed.

```
<Grid>
    <controls:GroupingGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResultsByOutcome}}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTest}"
                                ShowGroupingItemCount="True"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=GroupByOutcome, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=TestExplorer_Outcome}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="unitTesting:TestMethod">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Result.Outcome, Converter={StaticResource OutcomeIconConverter}}" Height="16" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=TestExplorer_QualifiedModuleName}" Binding="{Binding Declaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName}"
                                Width="{Binding OutcomeColumnWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=TestExplorer_MethodName}" Binding="{Binding Declaration.IdentifierName}"
                                Width="{Binding ModuleColumnWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=TestExplorer_Message}" Binding="{Binding Result.Output}"
                                Width="{Binding MessageColumnWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=TestExplorer_Duration}" Binding="{Binding Result.Duration, StringFormat={}{0}ms}" 
                                Width="{Binding DurationColumnWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:GroupingGrid>
    <controls:GroupingGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResultsByModule}}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTest}"
                                ShowGroupingItemCount="True"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=GroupByLocation, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=TestExplorer_Outcome}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="unitTesting:TestMethod">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Result.Outcome, Converter={StaticResource OutcomeIconConverter}}" Height="16" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=TestExplorer_QualifiedModuleName}" Binding="{Binding Declaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName}" 
                                Width="{Binding OutcomeColumnWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=TestExplorer_MethodName}" Binding="{Binding Declaration.QualifiedName.MemberName}" 
                                Width="{Binding ModuleColumnWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=TestExplorer_Message}" Binding="{Binding Result.Output}"
                                Width="{Binding MessageColumnWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=TestExplorer_Duration}" Binding="{Binding Result.Duration, StringFormat={}{0}ms}"
                                Width="{Binding DurationColumnWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:GroupingGrid>
</Grid>
```

The view model inherits from an abstract class `ViewModelBase` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The abstract class also has `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged` and the method `OnPropertyChanged`. I've set breakpoints on both `get` and `set` for the property and neither are ever reached.

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid Columns are not part of the logical or visual tree as they are abstract objects so they don't have access to the DataContext of your ViewModel. Which makes them rather difficult to bind to. Good news is that there are few ways you can do this.

**Proxy Object**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Descriptions}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"
                                Width="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Binding="{Binding Description}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

For further reading I recommend having a look at https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/ as it gives a good overview as to why and gives an alternative to the code above using a specific ProxyClass he creates.

Comment: I've added a ProxyClass which exposes a member for the column width. On first loading the width is set `public DataGridLength Header1Width { get; set; } = 250;` and the column in the same width for both `GroupingGrid`s. When the width of the column changes and the second grid is shown the width hasn't been updated. I can update the second grid's width and both are saved individually. It's like there is a distinct field for each and I can't figure out how to have both look at a single field.